# How to call a web service using XDocument?

Tags: c#, asmx

Suppose I have an asmx web service at the following address:
http://localhost/BudgetWeb/Service.asmx

This web service has a web method with the following signature:

```
string GetValue(string key)
```

This GetValue method returns a string like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><value>250.00</value>
```

What if I wanted to do this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://localhost/BudgetWeb/Service.asmx?op=GetValue&key=key1")
```

This doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure that XDocument.Load doesn't actually invoke a web method on the server. I think it expects the uri to point to a file that it can load. To call a web method, I think I'd have to have a web proxy class and would have to use that to call `string GetValue(string key)`, and then I could use that value returned from the web proxy class to pass to the XDocument.Load method.

Is my understanding correct, or is there a way for XDocument.Load to actually invoke a web method on the server?

Comment: If your client requires a webservice that needs to be consumed either by service references, and by HTTP, go with WCF, and not ASMX. WCF supports multiple endpoints for a service: f.e. one for REST (HTTP communication, using POST and GET) and one for SOAP. Easily consumed by both .Net, Java and other frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(
        "http://localhost/BudgetWeb/Service.asmx/GetValue?key=key1");
```

**EDIT:** Just figured out: you're using a invalid URI:

```
http://localhost/BudgetWeb/Service.asmx?op=GetValue&key=key1
```

Should be

```
http://localhost/BudgetWeb/Service.asmx/GetValue?key=key1
```

I'm using this code snippet:

```
string uri = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT";
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(uri);
Console.WriteLine(doc1.Root.Value);  // <StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>MSFT...
```

Comment: When I try that, I get System.Xml.XmlException: The 'input' start tag on line 71 does not match the end tag of 'td'. Line 71, position 98. It's basically the same error as I was getting without the XmlReader.Create part.

Comment: Your xml is not formatted properly, this is not a problem with the Load. Use http://validator.w3.org/ to validate a sample call.

Comment: Sorry for that, it was a typo. I still get same exception though.

Comment: Also, I tried it with the other URI you posted above but still get same error.

Comment: Thanks for that sample, it put me on the right track. However, the final solution turned out to be something I needed to add to the web.config for the web service (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the issue. In the web.config for the web service, you have to add this:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions, I really appreciate it, especially Rubens Farias whose working example put me on the right track.

Comment: You wrote it before I had a chance. But now you can see the Load works. Also why are you doing this instead of creating a Service Reference?

Comment: Yes, it works now and thanks again for the great help. The clientrequirement is that the web service call be invoked as a uri instead of using a service reference, so I don't have the option of using a service reference.  I am mocking the web service for my testing, and I left out the protocol stuff which is why it wasn't working, in addition to having some problems with the uri itself as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: @dcp: If Rubens Farias example helped then you should mark that as an answer.